How to redirect stage.mydomain.com to mydomain.com/stage?
I want to redirect subdomain to url.
For example, stage.mydomain.com should be accessed through mydomain.com/stage.
Subdomain is linked with static page on Amazon s3.
Domain is registered with Amazon Route 53.

This type of redirect is not possible with Amazon Route 53.
Domain names can only redirect to another domain name. It is not possible for DNS resolution to redirect to a particular path (eg /stage) of a domain.
You would need a web server listening on stage.mydomain.com that uses Redirections in HTTP - HTTP | MDN to instruct the browser to go to a different URL (which can contain a path).
Since your subdomain is pointing to an Amazon S3 bucket, you can Configure a webpage redirect rule - Amazon Simple Storage Service. This will tell S3 to redirect users to a different URL.
